# New to Linux-No midi sound in Ubuntu studio 19.10

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, midi

I am new to Linux but have used Win DAWs. I came upon Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and decided to give it a try. I have sound online (YouTube) but when I load up a DAW and try play a midi file, there us no sound. Does it work out of the box or Is there some configuration I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, there are some DAWs e.g. Audacity, Ardour, LMMS and etc. They play some MIDI formats. If it doesn't set output speakers of your machine automatically, you need to find out why. https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/midi

Comment: Okay, I'll go over there and ask. Thanks.

Comment: For a Midi file, which is basically a textfile to play you need to have programm that outputs the interpretation of the MIDI file to a synthesizer (which can either be a software synthesizer (see here https://www.linuxlinks.com/synthesizers/) or a hardware synthesizer via usb or midi port.